# Getting value in brackers regexp

Tags: regex

I have string and regexp that parses it.
String:

```
wallet: testing
addr: RpiDC8c1SxrT7RkXiKmXoQ1B8otHVSxuAT7jnxv2pBqyjARGqcZNdqKncRyDxVuGLsAuXBnWTV8YEdkFHzrY278BRuZXMNpSgQAeaFU3
balance:
     0.000 (30000005) COIN
```

Regexp: `[(:\\)\\t]{1,1}([^\\\\\\n\\t]+)[\\\\(|\\n|\\r]{1,1}`

Now I'm getting all values. Among them there is 0.000.
I need to get 30000005 instead of 0.000. How to change regexp to get 30000005?

Comment: `{1,1}` is redundant.

Comment: Do you need [someting like this](https://regex101.com/r/jkRySq/2)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to capture all numbers occurring inside parentheses, then I would simply use this regex:

```
\(\d+\)
```

If your regex tool doesn't have capture groups, then you may use lookarounds to match the exact number:

```
(?<=\()\d+(?=\))
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe these expressions would be somewhat close to what might be desired here:

```
\s\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)|:\s*(.*)
\s\(\s*(\d+)\s*\)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FG8Hpo/1)